# Не работает запуск программы android

Tags: java, android, gradle

Помогите пожалуйста.

```
package kuc.kuman.newproject;

public class Testclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Ввожу элементарную программу и запускаю нажатием зеленого треугольника, чтобы получить текст на консоли. В итоге вот что приходит:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Initialization script 'C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\Testclass_main__.gradle' line: 20
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Could not create task ':app:Testclass.main()'.
>     SourceSet with name 'main' not found.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Все перепробовал. Ничего не помогло. Ставил Андроид Студио на новый ноут с Виндой 10 и всеми обновлениями. В то же время, если кнопку не нажимать, то через AVD все работает. Программа компилируется. После нажатия зеленой кнопки и получения ошибки, AVD  в этом проекте уже не работает. На стационарном компьютере с Windows 7 все работает без проблем.

Comment: Поиведеный код - это вся ваша "элементарная программа"?

Comment: Ну как сказать? Я создал Empty Activity. Следом новый класс. Его я и запустил.

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с азами написания приложений под андроид, а потом уже браться за собственно написание. То, что вы написали, к андроиду вообще никак не относится. PS. Вы пишите "программа компилируется", хотя в первой же строчке сообщения об ошибке написано "Build **failed**"

Comment: Во первых я только учусь, при том самостоятельно и как раз азы. Во вторых, все эти манипуляции я успешно делал на первом стационарном компьютере. Там у меня все получается. В третьих всё тоже самое я делаю в Эклипсе и у меня так же все получается. Здесь же (на ноутбуке) не работает. Эта ошибка возникает у многих, но решения я нигде не нашел. Если вы можете чем то помочь, то будьте добры напишите что не так. Остальные советы не интересны.

Comment: что такое AVP ?

Comment: Извиняюсь - AVD

Comment: я решительно не понимаю, что вы пишите и под какую платформу, но с уверенностью могу сказать, что под андроид нет точки входа с main(), а десктопное java-приложение не запуститься в AVD.  И тот и другой случай не будет работать и абсолютно не понятно, что где и каким образом у вас может запускаться. Так же решительно не понятно, что у вас может работать в AVD без компиляции (нажатия на зеленый треугольник)

Comment: Буду сам разбираться. Я смог только что решить одну из проблем. Значит вскоре и всю проблему решу. Не в первой.

Comment: @Роман, технически в Android Studio можно писать и запускать pure-java код,  так как она она является модификацией IntelliJ IDEA и поддерживает разработку Андроид-совместимых java-библиотек. "Хелловорлд" вроде вашего должен бы выполниться. Но всё же надо понять что вы хотите - писать для Андроида или для JavaSE. Если для Андроида, то тестировать код запуском "main" на ПК нецелесообразно - поскольку на ПК и реальном Android-аппарате он может выполняться по-разному из-за разницы в реализации. Тестировать код лучше junit-тестами - они выполняются на ПК, но учитывают и ограничивают эту разницу

Comment: Но не на 100% - поэтому критические места надо тестировать инструментальными тестами, которые выполняются на устройстве/эмуляторе

Comment: Если же вы хотите писать полноценный JavaSE код, не ограничиваясь консолью, то студия для этого не подходит - лучше поставить "чистую" IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans, что то ещё. Все из перечисленных существуют для win/mac/linux. IDEA, как уже говорилось, является базой Андроид студии и через плагины поддерживает его разработку, в остальном имеет  идентичный интерфейс

Answer (score 1):

Программа на андроид не имеет точки входа с методом main(), как в десктопной Java.
 Точка входа здесь - активити, указанная в манифесте приложения стартовой, эта активити выполняет методы старта жизненного цикла, как onCreate(), onStart() и т.д. в них и происходит запуск программы.

Структура приложения на андроид вообще не имеет ничего общего с программами на десктопной Java. Хотя фреймворк Android и использует язык Java при написании кода, это совершенно особенная экосистема с иными принципами функционирования и исполнения.

Если вы хотите писать код для десктопной Java, используйте IntelliJ IDEA, если хотите писать под андроид - начните с чтения литературы по теме андроид-разработки, наивно полагать, что вы можете писать код под платформу, о работе которой не имеете даже минимального представления.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Ошибся в метках. Андроид изменил на Java

Comment: @РоманКуцый Если ваша программа для десктопной Java, то решение в этом ответе тоже есть - использовать IntelliJ IDEA, а не Android Studio, которая заточена именно на андроид-разработку и по умолчанию не имеет никаких инструментов для десктопной. так же в случае десктопной разработки совершенно непонятно, для чего вы создаете EmtyActivity, это узкоспециализированный класс-контроллер исключительно фреймворка андроид и в десктопной программе абсолютно чуждый элемент

Comment: Android Studio. Она работает как под Windows, так и под Linux. Вся проблема в том, что на стационарном компьютере с Windows 7 у меня все работает, а на ноутбуке с Windows 10 не работает. Действия я делал что там, что там идентичные.

Answer (score 0):

В Android Studio есть настройка проекта:

> File-Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment-Gradle-Runner "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle"

Чтоб запускались на выполнение методы psvm(main) ваших классов, нужно снять выбор этой опции.

Также можно сделать эту настройку по дефолту для всех проектов. Для этого надо закрыть проект, откроется стартовое окно Android Studio, зайти в

> Configure-Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment-Build Tools-Gradle-Runner

и также снять галочку с опции "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle".

Если у вас более поздняя версия Android Studio, то данная настройка недоступна из меню Settings. При этом можно принудительно выставить переменную delegatedBuild в false. Для этого заходим в папку проекта `Your_Project\.idea\` и редактируем файл `gradle.xml`. После тега

```
<GradleProjectSettings\>
```

вставляем строчку

```
<option name="delegatedBuild" value="false" />"
```